# problem .htaccess not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i write .htaccess in folder directory and run my site but nothing happend in url

example

index.php and add link to showpage.php?id=14

i want to change to products/14

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
# Turn on the rewriting engine  
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ showpage.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 
# Handle product requests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess will not magically rewrite links you've already added to your code. It's simply a tool for Apache to handle *incoming* requests.

In your `index.php` file, change the link from `showpage.php?id=14` to `products/14`. Reload the page in your browser. Provided that the rule is correctly set up (it looks correct), clicking the link should show the right URL in the address bar, and the right page content as well.

Comment: thank you Mr.vonconrad. i find this problem for aweek and nothing help me Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess must be enabled to function. In the apache config AllowOverwrite rewrite must be enabled. A short example

```
<Directory /foo/bar/>
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```